# Adding inputs on the fly jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if I could get some help with jquery. This is the html I have now:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/9sX6X/4/

```
<form name="input">
<input id="current" type="text" name="content" placeholder="content">
<input type="submit" value="Add" id="add">
</form>
```

What I want to do is when the user clicks "add" and as long as the input field isnt empty, I want to do the following:

- Change that input field id to "accepted" and remove the add button
  next to it and replace it with a remove button
- Add an input field below the original one with the id to "current"
  with an add button next to it

I want this process to happen every time the add button is clicked so more and more input boxes can spawn under each other. As far as I got was trying to spawn input boxes but even that doesn't work.

```
function addField(){
$('#add').append('<input type="text" name="myinput" />');
return false;
}
```

Can anyone please show me how this should be achieved.

Comment: You are appending to the wrong element, an input can't contain another element

Comment: If you try to change the id to accepted for every input type , you will face problems.Ids should be unique

Comment: You need to append to the form, not the submit button for starters

Comment: You are going to end up with confusing code to maintain if controls are changing id. If you need to mark a control with a certain property you should add a class or property - not change the id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it isn't a good solution to clone existing elements every time. Instead I would suggest cloning ... well... clones )) The original `input` and `button` remain the same, only visually shifted.

Is this behavior needed? - http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/9sX6X/6/

Answer (score 1):

Use `before()`

```
$('#add').before('<input type="text" name="myinput" />');
```

since you need to append the new input just before your submit button (and not into it, which is not possible here, since it's an input element)

Comment: you're not calling the `addField` function. Right now when you click the button you're just sending the form: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/MnAGZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

A working example http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/9sX6X/12/

```
$('form').on('click', '.add', function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('div'),
        new_row = row.clone();

    row.find('input:text').addClass('accepted');

    row.find('.add')
        .removeClass('add')
        .addClass('remove')
        .val('Remove');

    new_row.find('input:text').val('');

    row.after(new_row);
}).on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

Comment: I would suggest removing the `id`s because they are cloned in your version